# Dropdown on Firefox don't display elements after open it

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, cross-browser

I have a dropdown search component that I implemented for a web app and it work fine in chrome and edge. But when I tested it on Firefox it doesn't display the list of elements. it toggle the outside container but the elements are invisible. I checked the HTML on inspector the list is there.

The way this component work is simple I just toggle a class on the list that change the display from none to block.

I tried to add css prefixes but it doesn't work.

Is there anything I'm missing here or a properties that I need to add for Firefox?

Comment: Ah, best to show all of your code as otherwise it will cause confusion to those trying to help :)

Comment: Hi! Can you please show your code?